# wp8 Set header's size of dynamic pivot item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm a beginner in windows phone developpement, i've created a pivot application, the pivot's items are filled dynamically, but i can't ajust the fontsize of each titles and i don't know why, this is the xaml interface :

```
<phone:Pivot  VerticalAlignment="Top"  Name="pivotMainList">
    <phone:PivotItem   Name="titleToday" Margin="12,4,12,0">
        <phone:PivotItem.Header>
           <TextBlock Text="MainPage" FontSize="40"/>
        </phone:PivotItem.Header>
        <Grid Height="357">
           <ListBox ... // some code
```

and this is the code behind :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    var textBlock = new TextBlock { Text = "Pivot " + i, FontSize = 32 };
    PivotItem myNewPivotItem = new PivotItem { Header = textBlock, Name = "piv_" + i };
    Grid myNewGrid = new Grid();
    //... i fill the grid here

    //add pivot to main list
    pivotMainList.Items.Add(myNewPivotItem);
}
```

And it gives a weird exception:

> HappyConf.DLL!HappyConf.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of changing the font is to create a custom header template resource and then bind the header template property of the pivot to the resource.

Here's an example:

This code should be in the App.xaml file in the application resource section.

**XAML**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SmallPanoramaTitle">
        <ContentPresenter>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
        </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now for the code behind.
**C#**

```
myNewPivotItem.HeaderTemplate = Resource["SmallPanoramaTitle"] as HeaderTemplate;
```

Comment: Where exactly should this be placed in the Pivot Style?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not applying the DataTemplate "SmallPanoramaTitle" in C#, you can apply it in XAML as followed:

```
<phone:Pivot Title"Pivot" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource SmallPanoramaTitle}">
```